# Is the sefer אור הצפון available?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

Does anyone know where to get the sefer ohr hatzfon, containing mussar of the Alter of Slabadka, either online for free or by buying an actual copy?

Comment: http://www.virtualgeula.com/Stock/Books/Show/10878

Comment: I'll try to ask some of my Chofetz Chaim Yeshiva buddies where to get one BN BH.

Comment: I have a pdf of pages 1-150 if you're interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this publication has been out of print for several years, I am in the midst of its digitization. We will also be uploading it uploading to Sefaria.org, as well as making it available for general purchase.

Edit:
Its now on [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_HaTzafun) and [wikitext](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9F). Please let met know if you discover anything which requires correcting, it is also available for purchase (see [here](https://greatneckkollel.org/2021/02/03/ohr-hatzafun-digitization-complete/)).

Answer (score 4):

Here are the links to sections 1, 3, 4, and 5

- 1: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=304
- 2: Anyone got any idea where this is?
- 3: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31561
- 4: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31562
- 5: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31563

Comment: The snippet on Daat includes the material on the other three.

Comment: I didn't see the other 3 sections on daat... Is it in the PDF at the link I posted?

Comment: Yes. The same booklets that made it to HebrewBooks are included in the book excerpt on Daat. Different pages, same content.

Answer (score 3):

It is available for purchase and printing [here](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?103106). Hatzlacha.

Answer (score 3):

Ohr ha'Tzafon is out of print.  Try search in a store with little traffic and old inventory-off the beaten path.

Comment: Walter, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this advice! Can you suggest a particular store? I hop you'll look around the site and find other stuff worth reading, perhaps including our 56 other [tag:mussar] questions. Finally, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 0):

This sefer is on Otsar Hachochma and [3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31561) [small](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31562) [sections](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31562) are on Hebrewbooks.